# How to write ouput of a function to a file?

Tags: python-2.7

f=open('some_file.txt', 'a')
chars = "ACGT"

def neighbors2(pattern, d):

```
sum ([neighbors(pattern, d2) for d2 in range(d + 1)], [])


for i in range(0,len(sum)):
    f.write(sum[i])
f.close()
assert(d <= len(pattern))

if d == 0:
    return [pattern]

r2 = neighbors(pattern[1:], d-1)
r = [c + r3 for r3 in r2 for c in chars if c != pattern[0]]

if (d < len(pattern)):
    r2 = neighbors(pattern[1:], d)
    r += [pattern[0] + r3 for r3 in r2]

return r
```

I'm trying to write the output of this function (which is a string for ex:ACG) excluding the pattern ' '.But the code i tried produces an error . 
Error produced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test14.py", line 9, in neighbors2
    for i in range(0,len(sum)):
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

**UPDATE:**
I managed to the write the function output to a file.But I need to know how to remove ' ' marks from the list :(

Comment: what error it produces?

Comment: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: include the full traceback of the error by editing the question. Don't put it in comments

Comment: I have edited :)

Comment: What is `sum(len)` supposed to do?

Comment: sum(len) takes the length of the list sum.

Answer (score 0):

Use `with`, e.g.

```
with open('some_file.txt', 'a') as f:
    for i in range(len(pattern)):
        f.write('%d\n' % i)
```

That ensures the file is properly `close()`d upon exiting the block.

Also, omit parens on conditionals. Use `if d < 2:`, not `if (d < 2):`.

And definitely omit parens around an assert. Phrase it as `assert d <= len(pattern)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But it gives the error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test14.py", line 8, in neighbors2
    for i in range(len(sum)):
TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()" seems like I can't iterate the output of the function.

Comment: Thanks I can now write the output to a file. But I still can't remove ' ' from the string :(